# How to change text color in jQuery animate?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am trying to change text color using jquery animate like this:

```js
$(p).hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({"color":"red"})
})
```

But my code is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: jquery doesn't support it directly. you have to use some plugins. Try this plugin. http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: jQuery does not animate colors, you'll need to add jQuery UI or a color animation plugin for that, also the p in the selector is not quoted, so that has to be a variable.

Comment: Did you meant `$(p)` or `$('p')` ??

Answer (score 14):

Without using any additional plugin: I know this question is pretty old now but this is to help anyone still looking for a solution... here is a workaround without the need of any additional plugin.

jQuery css to change the color:

```
$("p").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("color","red");
})
```

and CSS transition to replicate the animation effect when the color changes:

```
p {
color: black;
-webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition: color 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: color 0.4s ease;
transition: color 0.4s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply acheive it with **Jquery UI**. After adding simply

```
$( "#effect" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
          color: "#fff",
          width: 500
        }, 1000 );
```

http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Add two buttons. The forecolor of the first button will change on click of the second button.

```
<input type="button" id="bt" value="Change My Color" />
<input type="button" id="bt1" value="Change the Color" />

<script>
    $('#bt1').click(function() {
        $('#bt').animate({ color: 'red' }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the JQuery script [here](http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/color-changing-text.php) for color changing effect.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: not only what @Benjamin said, but this script is a terrible example of good JavaScript practices. Really, there are NO good practices in the link provided. Down voting.

Answer (score 0):

2019, use interpolator syntax, and rgb ranges 0 to 255. Good to animate any css number.

```
//changes txt color from black to white, then white to red, then red to blue.
$({'r':0,'g':0,'b':0}).animate({'r':255,'g':255,'b':255},{queue:false,duration:3000, easing:'swing',
  step: function(now) { 
    nx.ui.txtSection.css('color','rgb('+this.r+','+this.g+','+this.b+')'); 
  }, complete:function(){
    $({'r':255,'g':255,'b':255}).animate({'r':255,'g':0,'b':0},{queue:false,duration:3000, easing:'swing',
      step: function(now) { 
          nx.ui.txtSection.css('color','rgb('+this.r+','+this.g+','+this.b+')');
      }, complete:function(){
        $({'r':255,'g':0,'b':0}).animate({'r':0,'g':0,'b':255},{queue:false,duration:3000, easing:'swing',
          step: function(now) { 
              nx.ui.txtSection.css('color','rgb('+this.r+','+this.g+','+this.b+')');
          }, complete:function(){
          } //NEXT-SUB-SEQUENCE-. 
        });
      } //NEXT-SUB-SEQUENCE-. 
    });
  } //NEXT-SUB-SEQUENCE-. 
});

//Here is the minimum pattern... worth learning to easily animate any css-.
$({'r':0,'g':0,'b':0}).animate({'r':0,'g':255,'b':0},{queue:false,duration:3000, easing:'swing',
  step: function(now) { 
    nx.ui.txtSection.css('color','rgb('+this.r+','+this.g+','+this.b+')');
  }, complete:function(){
  } //NEXT-SUB-SEQUENCE-. 
});
```