# How to change the text color with .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to flash some text when it will be updated with new informations. For that I need a transition. Cause the information will be updated all 60 seconds I want to use the jQuery .animate method.

For some reason it won´t work to change the text color. Margin and other stuff works fine. Is there a way to change the textcolor linear?

```js
$('html').click(function() {
  $('div').animate({ color: 'red', 'margin': '200px' }, 700);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test">My Text</div>
```

Comment: You should really read the documentation before asking. http://api.jquery.com/animate/ - it explicitly mentions what properties can be animated, and for which you will need something extra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change text color in jquery animate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871967/how-to-change-text-color-in-jquery-animate)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by adding animated class after click event. Please check below solution:

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('div').addClass('animated');
});

body {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
}

.animated {
 margin:200px;
 color:red;
 transition:all .7s;
}
```

and fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1wfnyuez/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a class to apply the styling and then after a timeout - remove the class to return to the default styling. The following adds a class to transition the test div and after 2 secs remove that class.

Note that the OP and the other answers all follow the same pattern by altering the styling in the js - this is one way, but I would always suggest to leave the styling to the CSS and use the js to add / remove the styled class.

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('.test').removeClass('active');
  }, 2000)

});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.test {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out
}



.test.active {
  color: red;
  margin: 200px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test">My Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery-color for this. Or switch to classname transitions

```js
$('html').click(function() {
  $('div').animate({ color: 'red', 'margin': '200px' }, 700);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-Wp3wC/dKYQ/dCOUD7VUXXp4neLI5t0uUEF1pg0dFnAE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="test">My Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional css to change the color. Just a work-around

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html').click(function() {
  $('div').animate({  'margin': '200px'}, 700).css('color','red');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation principle of the animate method in jquery is to use the timer to gradually change the attribute value according to the step size. Therefore, only the numeric attribute change is supported, and the color does not have the decimal increase or decrease, so it cannot be realized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `complete` callback function to change the color:

```js
$('html').click(function() {
  $('div').animate({ 'margin': '200px' }, 700, function () {
    $('div').css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test">My Text</div>
```